# running perl cgi script problec

Tags: macos, perl, apache, osx-lion, cgi

I am trying to run a simple hello world script as CGI (from the Beginning Perl book).
i am running to the following problems:

1. I do not find a folder `/cgi-bin/` at any place on my computer (Mac OSX Lion).
   I did try changing mode to 755 and any thing i found on the web.
2. when I try the localhost, I get "it works!" (this means the apache is working o.k)
3. I saw some advice on changing configurations on apache files and there are confusing
   never the less i did try and all did not work.
   for instance, the advice to check and uncheck the web button in sharing does no work in 
   mac osx lion, there isn't a button of that kind any more.

Is it possible to get a step by step guide or help on what to do from the Perl script to actually running it on the web server?

Comment: Lion removed per user directories from the default configuration. You need to [manually enable them](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/57555/17740). The "It works" page is from the system directories.

Answer (score 1):

> i do not find a folder /cgi-bin/ at any place on my computer (mac osx lion).

You can create one.

The Apache manual [describes how to configure it for executing CGI](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html#configuring).

> when i try the localhost , i get "it works!" (this means the apache is working o.k)

You need to use the URI to the CGI script rather than the Apache root.

> i sow some advice on changing configurations on apache files and there are confusing never the less i did try and all did not work. for instance, the advice to check and uncheck the web button in sharing does no work in mac osx lion, there isn't a button of that kind any more.

Apple did remove the GUI option. Instead of using it, fall back to the command line:

```
apachectl restart
```

It is usually a good idea to first check your config file edits with:

```
apachectl configtest
```